Drawing up a staircase for permit application

I would like to turn this design of the staircase into a drawing appropriate for permit application. I've spent a couple of days perusing through the county permit website. I understand what the code says and how the stairs should be made, but I just don't know what the drawing is supposed to look like. If I had an idea, I could begin to draw it up. I even emailed the county department for an example, and they didn't have one to share with me.

Can you provide a link to the county permit website?

https://www.portland.gov/ppd/residential-permitting/residential-projects/stairs

So...your sketch looks like a deck, which would fall under a different permit regime than the one you linked, IMO. This document may be of use to you: https://www.portland.gov/sites/default/files/2020/res_deck_060716-2.pdf  (Here's decks in general: https://www.portland.gov/ppd/residential-permitting/residential-projects/decks)

I mentioned in the title and the comment that I'm building a staircase. I did draw the deck as well just because it helps me visualize everything better. The deck already exists along with the railing.

But are you building deck stairs, or interior stairs?
